# How can i remove duplicate strings from array in python

Tags: python

I have an array in which I'm getting duplicating string that is matching within the other string how can I check and remove from others strings if have

This is the array that I'm getting and I want to remove the duplication string from the array.

```
"titles": [
        "Financial Analyst",
        "Analyst",
        "Respiratory Therapist",
        "Therapist",
        "Healthcare Specialist",
        "Specialist",
        "Liaison",
        "Business Development Analyst",
        "Development Analyst",
        "Sales Team",
        "Data Analyst",
        "Administrator",
        "Auditor",
        "Director",
        "Director of Events",
        "Controller"
    ]
```

let me define which I want.
I have two strings in the array
`Financial Analyst` & `Analyst` I want to remove the second one from the array because this string comes in the first string.
also like one more example `Healthcare Specialist` & `Specialist` the second one I want to remove.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about "Director" and "Director of Events" ? Delete the 2nd one or not ?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that if a word appears in another, the single word should be removed and the composed not ?

Comment: @Rabinzel I want to remove single which are coming in the other string. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as optimization isn't a problem, you can easily achieve this using a for-loop. Here is the code with comments explaining it:

```py
titles = [
        "Financial Analyst",
        "Analyst",
        "Respiratory Therapist",
        "Therapist",
        "Healthcare Specialist",
        "Specialist",
        "Liaison",
        "Business Development Analyst",
        "Development Analyst",
        "Sales Team",
        "Data Analyst",
        "Administrator",
        "Auditor",
        "Director",
        "Director of Events",
        "Controller"
    ]   # Create the example titles array

for i in range(len(titles)-1, -1, -1):    # Loop through the titles from top to bottom
    for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):  # Loop through the titles up until i from top to bottom
        if titles[i] in titles[j]:
            titles.remove(titles[i])

        elif titles[j] in titles[i]:
            titles.remove(titles[j])

print(titles)
```

Note that you have two if statements so that the order of the array doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar approach with a list comprehension, removing members that are inside any other string in the `titles` list.

```
titles = [
        "Financial Analyst",
        "Analyst",
        "Respiratory Therapist",
        "Therapist",
        "Healthcare Specialist",
        "Specialist",
        "Liaison",
        "Business Development Analyst",
        "Development Analyst",
        "Sales Team",
        "Data Analyst",
        "Administrator",
        "Auditor",
        "Director",
        "Director of Events",
        "Controller"
    ]

titles = [title for title in titles if not any([title != _title and title in _title for _title in titles])]
```

Result:

```
[
    "Financial Analyst",
    "Respiratory Therapist",
    "Healthcare Specialist",
    "Liaison",
    "Business Development Analyst",
    "Sales Team",
    "Data Analyst",
    "Administrator",
    "Auditor",
    "Director of Events",
    "Controller"
]
```